# how to fill a java server `LocalDate` from angularjs client

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

in my angular js code I have date as string:

```
        self.submit = function () {
            console.log("in voice prompt component - submit");
            console.log(self.voice);

            self.fromDate = new Date(self.fromDate);



            $http.put('http://localhost:8082/api/Voices/updateVoice', self.fromDate).then(
                function successCallback(response) {
                    self.voices = response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    console.log(response);

                });

        }
```

I want to send it to my server: `LocalDate` from Java 8

```
@Path("/updateVoice")
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public void updateVoice(LocalDate fromDate) throws Exception {
```

but i get an error:

```
Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-04-04T21:00:00.000Z')
```

Comment: Spring? Joda? Please specify which libraries you're using.

Comment: in the JS side you send `self.voice` and not the date you have created : `self.fromDate`.  Are you sure of the code ?

Comment: @davidxxx i fixed this

Comment: It is much better. I have answered.